# String types not allowed (at 'background' with value )

Tags: android, android-studio, android-background

I'm having trouble adding a image to my background, I saw a similar question earlier and none the answers helped me. Ive tried everything "@drawables/myimagename", "myimagename.png", and "myimagename" none of these things seem to work. I even tried to put in the path of the picture, and still nothing.

Comment: i tried that the drawable/myimage  but i get this error :Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/atl1.png  Failed to convert @drawable/myimage into a drawable. im using a png if that matters

Comment: guys i feel like a freaking idot, i kept putting .png after myimage (myimage.png) that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

> Ive tried everything "@drawables/myimagename"

To set image from  `drawable,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,...` folder's use `@drawable/[image_name]` instead of `@drawables` :

```
android:background="@drawable/myimagename"
```

Answer (score 1):

you must want that folder
name drawable and you also call it like

```
android:background="@drawable/myimagename"
```

and the name  `myimagename` must be typed like in the file name in the folder

Answer (score 1):

try this instead.

go to **values** -> **colour.xml**
  and delete

**color name="background">color**

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@drawables/`, use `@drawable/`

```
android:background="@drawable/myimagename"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

```
@drawable/myimagename
```

instead of

```
@drawables/myimagename
```

Make sure you have the image named myimagename in the drawable folder of your application